# Android Material Design values.xml errors

Tags: android, material-design

I am creating an app with `AppCompatActivity`.

I use `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'` in my `build.gradle` to use Material Design but I always receiving these errors:

> aapt: Attribute "android:alpha" has already been defined

> aapt: Attribute "android:translationX" has already been defined

> aapt: Attribute "android:translationY" has already been defined

> aapt: Attribute "android:translationZ" has already been defined

`build.gradle` files:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dlv.mydiary"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
}
```

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.+'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

I removed 3 `declare-styleable` as it's caused an error but it's getting worst.

[image: Image Errors]

Do you know how to fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your module-level `build.gradle` file?

Comment: This is the project-level `build.gradle` file. You should put custom dependencies in the module-level `build.gradle` file. This may be the cause of the problem.

Comment: @LucaPizzini, I've tried but no changes

Answer (score 0):

check if you do not use the same attributes names. So check all youre libraries.

Comment: I checked it and Material Design is using already defined attributes, I tried removing them and it's getting worst.

Answer (score 0):

update to compile version 29, you are on 210this might help you

Answer (score 0):

This can occur if multiple tags do the same thing.

Like how an `src` and `icon` tag can be the same thing.
If you use both within the same tag, it would give an error.

example-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.AboutFragment">

</LinearLayout>
```

here, as you can see, the `android:fitsSystemWindows` and `android:layout_height` both define how the layout fits to the screen. So, that is what causes the `already defined` errors.

Also, please explain why are the errors on a screenshot of an android device giving code errors. I'm sure many others have the same question.